# UDP broadcasting on same machine?

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, broadcast

I wrote a *broadcaster* and a *listener* which *recvfrom* a particular port on the system. I used REUSEADDR option for the socket in *listener*, to make multiple instances of *listener* monitor the same port on same system.

When I run the *listener* on different machines, and send packet from another machine, all the *listeners* receives the packet. but when I run multiple instances of *listener* on same machine and if I try sending udp packets, only the first instance of *listener* gets the packet not all. I want to broadcast UDP packets on same machine and want all the listeners to receive the packet. I am on linux.

I followed the Beej's Guide.

Edit 01

## listener code

```
/*
** listener.c -- a datagram sockets "server" demo
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define MYPORT "4950"   // the port users will be connecting to

#define MAXBUFLEN 100

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
        if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
        }

        return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int sockfd;
        struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
        int rv;
        int numbytes;
        struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
        char buf[MAXBUFLEN];
        socklen_t addr_len;
        char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

        int reuse_addr = 1;


        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // set to AF_INET to force IPv4
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

        if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, MYPORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
                return 1;
        }

        // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
        for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
                if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
                        perror("listener: socket");
                        continue;
                }

                if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {

                        if(errno == EADDRINUSE)
                        {
                                if(setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                                                &reuse_addr, sizeof reuse_addr) < 0)
                                        perror("setsockopt(): REUSEADDR\n"),exit(1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                close(sockfd);
                                perror("listener: bind");
                                continue;
                        }
                }
                break;
        }

        if (p == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "listener: failed to bind socket\n");
                return 2;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

        printf("listener: waiting to recvfrom...\n");

        addr_len = sizeof their_addr;
        if ((numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN-1 , 0,
                (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1) {
                perror("recvfrom");
                exit(1);
        }

        printf("listener: got packet from %s\n",
                inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
                        get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
                        s, sizeof s));
        printf("listener: packet is %d bytes long\n", numbytes);
        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("listener: packet contains \"%s\"\n", buf);

        close(sockfd);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What IP address is your sender sending to?  If it's sending to 127.0.0.1, then it's sending unicast packets and only one listener will receive them.  If it's sending to your local network's broadcast address (e.g. 192.168.0.255 if you're on a 192.168.0.x network, or 10.255.255.255 if you're on a 10.0.x.y network, and so on) then all the listeners should receive the packet.

Comment: I tried sending to 255.255.255.255, localhost and to 0.0.0.0. in all the cases only one listener gets the packet.

Comment: Try your LAN's broadcast address (which is basically your IP address bitwise-or'd with the bitwise-not of your netmask; e.g. for ip=192.168.2.5 netmask=255.255.255.0,  broadcast_address=(192.168.2.5 | 0.0.0.255) = 192.168.2.255

Comment: I tried that too now. it didn't work. I also tried to set SO_REUSEPORT option. but it seems it is not available in linux; gcc throws compilation error

Comment: can you post the listner code?

Comment: I did add the code. please have a look.

Comment: I believe the easiest way to achieve "local broadcast" is to instead use multicast. See this question: [OS support for an unprivileged interprocess bus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993338/linux-os-support-for-an-unprivileged-interprocess-bus)

Answer (score 0):

Set socket option to `SO_REUSEPORT` in linstener.

> SO_REUSEPORT - socket option allows multiple sockets on the same host to bind to the same port

Comment: SO_REUSEPORT is not available in linux, I think. when I compile, it gcc says SO_REUSEPORT is undeclared.

Comment: what is the OS and kernel version?

Comment: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c617f398edd4db2b8567a28e899a88f8f574798d

Comment: this is the output of *uname*
>>> Linux tsus007 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 11:41:38 EST 2008 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: is there any other method to broadcast on same machine?? mandatorily through UDP

Comment: Linux 3.9+ has an option called `SO_REUSEPORT`, but it facilitates load balancing, not broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

Make `accept_local` as `1` using echo in SYSFS.

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all # cat accept_local
1
```

This will allow local communication.